# Can't find DOMDocument class on PHP7 on top of Apache and Vagrant

Tags: php, vagrant

I'm running a local web app on top of Vagrant with Apache and PHP7.

I have been trying to add the broken dependency by many ways and so far I have not been able.

I'm using scotchbox and so far I have not found a solution from them.

This are some of the steps I'm following that solve other issues:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo composer self-update
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo apt-get install php7.0-soap
sudo service apache2 restart
composer install
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Class 'DOMDocument' not found

Filename: /var/www/mytestsite.local/public/application/third_party/vendor/symfony/serializer/Encoder/XmlEncoder.php

Line Number: 88

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/mytestsite.local/public/application/third_party/vendor/symfony/serializer/Encoder/ChainDecoder.php
Line: 40
Function: decode

File: /var/www/mytestsite.local/public/application/third_party/vendor/symfony/serializer/Serializer.php
Line: 269
Function: decode

File: /var/www/mytestsite.local/public/application/third_party/vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/AdWords/Reporting/v201609/ReportDownloader.php
Line: 149
Function: decode

File: /var/www/mytestsite.local/public/application/third_party/vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/AdWords/Reporting/v201609/ReportDownloader.php
Line: 126
Function: makeReportRequest

File: /var/www/mytestsite.local/public/application/libraries/Googleads.php
Line: 231
Function: downloadReportWithAwql

File: /var/www/mytestsite.local/public/application/controllers/Mbt.php
Line: 691
Function: getCostByAdGrp

File: /var/www/mytestsite.local/public/index.php
Line: 316
Function: require_once
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue here also with scotchbox, after installing symfony using their installer and wanting to run the demo project. (running symfony new demo on the box through ssh).

This is the error i got:

Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /var/www/public/demo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.php:52 Stack trace: #0

I followed Jean Paul Ruiz's advice but i am under the impression that more needs to be reinstalled to get the box to where it was. I was presented a white screen upon running the app in a browser.

I was able to solve the problem when I read this post on https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74865

Running php -i or php -m on the scotchbox gave me these errors too.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/dom.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/dom.so: undefined symbol: php_libxml_node_free_list in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlreader.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlreader.so: undefined symbol: dom_node_class_entry in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xsl.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/xsl.so: undefined symbol: dom_node_class_entry in Unknown on line 0
```

As indicated in the post above, the solution for me was to simply run **apt-get update** and **apt-get upgrade** on the scotchbox...after that the symfony app would run. TaDAAA!

Cheers
Henk

Comment: Hey @webjazznl, I have a gist here that might help you:

https://gist.github.com/jpruiz114/51d62dfa4d317329c14d3ebcdc6fd2f0

It's worth trying tho. It's a vagrant file that provisions a vagrant machine with scotch box but does some clean up for you.

Comment: But again, for a Laravel / Symfony project, I would rather use homestead:

https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead

Comment: In my opinion scotch box is just too unstable so at some point, I moved all my local projects to a Homestead Vagrant machine. It's supposed to be specific for PHP7 and laravel projects but it works just fine in most of the legacy PHP5 projects. Also works fine for projects with other PHP frameworks; I still use scotch box when I'm in a hurry and need an environment for legacy PHP project but you need to run too many things, update packages, add missing repos sources, fix the PHP version. You might have issues if you use htaccess files since this machine uses Nginx but it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so in the end, the solution was to purge PHP from the machine, re-install it and add the packages required:

purge php

```
sudo apt-get purge php.*
sudo service apache2 restart

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php
sudo service apache2 restart
```

start installing all the php packages

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
sudo service apache2 restart

sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
sudo service apache2 restart

sudo apt-get install php-xml
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope this helps anyone having the same issue.